# Grails: How to find Domain properties does not have any error

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

```
<div id="error-right" class="error-container ${!hasErrors(bean:user, 'hidden')}">
```

The above code I am trying to put a class "hidden" is there is error in my domain called user.

but its not working. 
Is there any better way of finding it inside GSP.

Answer (score 4):

```
<div id="error-right" class="error-container ${!user.hasErrors() ? 'hidden' : ''}">
```

Answer (score 0):

`g.hasErrors( bean:user, 'hidden' )` prints out the `'hidden'`, if the `user` bean does have errors, or empty string if it doesn't.

So, negating it's output is not what you want.

@gregg 's suggestion is correct